# setting up new account

Tags: support, user-accounts, new-users

Sorry -- this is likely duplicative, but I don't know where to find the answer. I have a friend who may want to set up an account. I can't remember where I went to set up my own account.  Also, I was asked to provide a facebook or gmail or something account.  Doubt if my friend has any of those.

What should I tell him to do?  We really, really want him here if we can get him.

Comment: People look at me weird for not having a Facebook account. I wonder what sort of looks your friend is getting for not even having a Google account... (But kudos for not having those.)

Comment: The thing about being elderly is that no one expects google or facebook.  He does have email thru his university.  Elderly does not seem to be slowing down him mathematics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you visit the site without an account, there is a "sign up" link at the top right. You can then use any OpenID provider to log in, the most common ones being Google, Facebook and Yahoo, or you can create an account with Stack Exchange.

If your friend doesn't have an existing Google or Facebook account, just tell them to create an account with Stack Exchange at that point (and maybe warn him that the password requirements for the Stack Exchange account are unusually strict in comparison to most sites).

You can also use the site without an account, though there are significant benefits for signing up and creating an account.

Comment: exactly what I needed to know -- thanks